# React useEffect not rerendering

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am trying to change a value in an array and rerender the component with useEffect but useEffect is not triggering. Value is being changed but calling useState has no effect.

```
const handleOptionClick = (e) => {

            var el = document.getElementById(e.currentTarget.id);
            var tar = el.getAttribute("data");
            
            var ans = awnsers;
            ans.map((res) => {
                if (res.Awnser === tar) {
                  res.IsChecked = !res.IsChecked;
                  return true;
                }
                return true;
              });
              setAwnsers(ans);
     }
```

and

```
useEffect(() => {
        console.log(awnsers);
    },[awnsers])
```

Comment: Hello, please update question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) component code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are doing a `map` on `ans`, I take it to be an array. Arrays are copied by reference. So for react to re-render the `awnsers`, you will have to create a new array.

```
var ans = [...awnsers]; // or JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(awnsers)) for deep clone
            ans.map((res) => {
                if (res.Awnser === tar) {
                  res.IsChecked = !res.IsChecked;
                  return true;
                }
                return true;
              });
              setAwnsers(ans);
```

Also is `Awnsers` a typo? Did you mean `Answers`?

Answer (score 0):

React performs an Object.is comparison while updating state and if the reference of previous and current state is same the check fails and a re-render is not triggered

Also map returns a new reference of the array and you must not mutate the original array but update it in an immutable manner

```
const handleOptionClick = (e) => {

        var el = document.getElementById(e.currentTarget.id);
        var tar = el.getAttribute("data");
        
        var ans = awnsers; // Check for typo
        ans = ans.map((res) => {
            if (res.Awnser === tar) {
              {...res, IsChecked:!res.IsChecked};
            }
            return res;
          });
          setAwnsers(ans);
 }
```

P.S. You can also make use of functional setState approach to update state since you are updating current state based on previous values

```
  const handleOptionClick = (e) => {

        var el = document.getElementById(e.currentTarget.id);
        var tar = el.getAttribute("data");
        setAwnsers(prevAns => ans.map((res) => {
            if (res.Awnser === tar) {
              {...res, IsChecked:!res.IsChecked};
            }
            return res;
        }));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't save the result of the array::map function that you save in state, so essentially the state reference values in the `awnsers` array don't change and the component won't re-render.

```
const handleOptionClick = (e) => {
  var el = document.getElementById(e.currentTarget.id);
  var tar = el.getAttribute("data");
        
  setAwnsers(prevAwnser => prevAwnser.map(res => ({
    ...res,
    IsChecked: res.Awnser === tar ? !res.IsChecked : res.IsChecked,
  })));
}
```